# How to use iOS auto-fill password feature for React Native application using Firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, authentication

I am trying to implement [Password Autofill](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/) feature for the iOS version of my React Native application that uses Firebase however I cannot get this to work.

All documentation I've seen for implementing this feature for React Native is pretty straightfoward however when it comes to hosting the apple-app-site-association in Firebase, there is some kind of disconnect. Below are the steps I take to try to implement this feature:

1. Add textContentType to username and password fields:

```
<TextInput
  style={styles.input}
  placeholderTextColor={QuietCollectionColors.gray}
  onBlur={onBlur}
  onChangeText={value => {
   setUsername(value);
   onChange(value);
  }}
  value={value}
  placeholder="Email"
  autoCapitalize="none"
  textContentType="username"
  keyboardType="email-address"
/>
<TextInput
  style={styles.input}
  placeholderTextColor={QuietCollectionColors.gray}
  onBlur={onBlur}
  onChangeText={value => {
    setPassword(value);
    onChange(value);
  }}
  value={value}
  placeholder="Password"
  secureTextEntry
  autoCapitalize="none"
  textContentType={'password' || 'newPassword'}
/>
```

2. In Apple Developer Account I enabled Associated Domains as an entitlement in the mobile provision profile
3. In Firebase I created a Dynamic link (e.g. https://[appname].page.link
4. When I test the apple-app-site-association file by navigating in my brower (https://[appname].page.link/apple-app-site-association) I see

```
{"applinks":{"apps":[],"details":[{"appID":"[DEV TEAM ID].com.[appname]","paths":["NOT /_/*","/*"]}]}}
```

5. In XCode, I set the Associated Domains to point to the site which will host the apple-app-site-association file.
   `webcredentials:[appname].page.link`

After these steps though, the autofill feature still does not work. I know I'm missing an important step but my Googling skills are coming up short today. Any ideas?

Comment: Same question. Different medium. No answers! I am shocked that more people are not trying to figure this out.